# Slow join and group by on indexed columns

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, sql-optimization

The following query takes 15-20s to run

```
SELECT "Trade_US"."ID" AS "Trade_US.ID",
"Server_US"."Name" AS "Server_US.Name",
"Trade_US"."TradeTypeID" AS "Trade_US.TradeTypeID",
"Users"."ID" AS "Users.ID",
"Users"."NickName" AS "Users.NickName",
"Item"."ID" AS "Item.ID",
"Item"."ItemTypeID" AS "Item.ItemTypeID",
"Item"."ItemQualityID" AS "Item.ItemQualityID",
"Item"."Level" AS "Item.Level",
"Item"."IconURL" AS "Item.IconURL",
"Trade_US"."Amount" AS "Trade_US.Amount",
"Trade_US"."BonusPercent" AS "Trade_US.BonusPercent",
"Trade_US"."StartBidTotalSilver" AS "Trade_US.StartBidTotalSilver",
"Trade_US"."BuyOutTotalSilver" AS "Trade_US.BuyOutTotalSilver",
"Trade_US"."Description" AS "Trade_US.Description",
"Trade_US"."LastUpdate" AS "Trade_US.LastUpdate",
"Trade_US"."LastBump" AS "Trade_US.LastBump",
CONCAT(COALESCE("ItemPrefix_Text_EN"."PrefixName",""),"Item_Text_EN"."ItemName") AS "FullItemName",
MAX("TradeOffer_US"."PriceTotalSilver") AS "BestOfferTotalSilver" 
FROM "Trade_US" 
  Inner JOIN "Users" ON (("Trade_US"."TraderUserID" = "Users"."ID"))
  Inner JOIN "Item" ON (("Trade_US"."ItemID" = "Item"."ID"))
  Inner JOIN "Item_Text_EN" ON (("Item"."ID" = "Item_Text_EN"."ItemID"))
  Inner JOIN "Server_US" ON (("Server_US"."ID" = "Trade_US"."GameServerID"))
  Left JOIN "ItemPrefix_Text_EN" ON (("ItemPrefix_Text_EN"."ItemPrefixID" = "Trade_US"."ItemPrefixID"))
  Left JOIN "TradeReply_US" ON (("TradeReply_US"."TradeID" = "Trade_US"."ID"))
  Left JOIN "TradeOffer_US" ON (("TradeOffer_US"."ReplyID" = "TradeReply_US"."ID"))
 GROUP BY "Trade_US"."ID"
 ORDER BY "Trade_US"."LastBump" desc LIMIT 300000, 10
```

Explain gives the following result
[image]

Here are the table definitions

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
    ID int primary key,

    NickName nvarchar(50) unique not null
);/*2 rows*/

CREATE TABLE ItemType(
    ID INT primary key,
    Name varchar(50) not null
);/*80 rows*/

CREATE TABLE ItemQuality(
    ID INT primary key,
    Name varchar(50) not null
);/*6 rows*/

CREATE TABLE Item(
    ID INT   primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ItemTypeID int not null,
    `Level` int not null,
    ItemQualityID int not null,
    IconURL varchar(100) not null,

    FOREIGN KEY (ItemTypeID) REFERENCES ItemType(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ItemQualityID) REFERENCES ItemQuality(ID)
);/*5k rows*/
CREATE INDEX Level ON Item(Level);

CREATE TABLE Item_Text_EN(
    ItemID int primary key,
    ItemName varchar(50) not null,

    FOREIGN KEY (ItemID) REFERENCES Item (ID)
);/*5k rows*/
CREATE INDEX ItemName ON Item_Text_EN(ItemName);

CREATE TABLE ItemPrefix(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PrefixTypeID INT not null,

    FOREIGN KEY (PrefixTypeID) REFERENCES ItemPrefixType(ID)
);/*100 rows*/

CREATE TABLE ItemPrefix_Text_EN(
    ItemPrefixID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    PrefixName nvarchar(50) not null,

    FOREIGN KEY (ItemPrefixID) REFERENCES ItemPrefix(ID)
);/*100 rows*/

CREATE TABLE Trade_US(
    ID INT primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    GameServerID int not null,
    TradeTypeID int not null,
    TraderUserID int not null,
    ItemID int not null,
    Amount int not null,
    BonusPercent int null,
    ItemPrefixID INT null,
    StartBidTotalSilver int null,
    BuyOutTotalSilver int not null,

    `Description` nvarchar(200) null,
    LastUpdate datetime not null,
    LastBump datetime not null,

    FOREIGN KEY (GameServerID) REFERENCES Server_US(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (TradeTypeID) REFERENCES TradeType(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (TraderUserID) REFERENCES Users(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ItemPrefixID) REFERENCES ItemPrefix(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ItemID) REFERENCES Item(ID),

    CHECK (BonusPercent >=0 ),
    CHECK (Amount > 0 AND Amount < 99999),
    CHECK (StartBidTotalSilver < 100000000 AND StartBidTotalSilver >= 0),
    CHECK (BuyOutTotalSilver < 100000000 AND BuyOutTotalSilver >= 0)
);/*1million duplicated rows*/
CREATE INDEX BonusPercent ON Trade_US (BonusPercent);
CREATE INDEX StartBidTotalSilver ON Trade_US (StartBidTotalSilver);
CREATE INDEX BuyOutTotalSilver ON Trade_US (BuyOutTotalSilver);
CREATE INDEX LastBump ON Trade_US (LastBump);

CREATE TABLE TradeReply_US(
    ID INT primary key NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    TradeID int not null,
    ReplyUserID int not null,
    `Message` nvarchar(200) null,
    `Time` datetime not null,

    FOREIGN KEY (ReplyUserID) REFERENCES Users(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (TradeID) REFERENCES Trade_US (ID) on delete cascade
);/*5 rows*/

CREATE TABLE TradeOffer_US(
    ReplyID int primary key,
    PriceTotalSilver int not null,

    FOREIGN KEY (ReplyID) REFERENCES TradeReply_US (ID) on delete cascade,
    CHECK (PriceTotalSilver < 100000000 AND PriceTotalSilver >= 0)
);/*2 rows*/

CREATE TABLE Server_US(
    ID INT primary key,
    Name varchar(20) not null
);/*3 rows*/
```

Profiling result:

```
17 Init 61 µs 
18 Optimizing 14 µs 
19 Statistics 158 µs 
20 Preparing 41 µs 
21 Creating Tmp Table 165 µs 
22 Executing 2 µs 
23 Copying To Tmp Table 14.2 s 
24 Sorting Result 972.5 ms 
25 Sending Data 1.1 s 
26 End 5 µs
```

*Any column named as ID is a primary key
*Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503
*Right now it doesnt have a where clause, but the user might choose to do a search which results in any combination of indexed columns being included in the where clause.

I have tried to remove all the group by clause + max(...) and it takes around 8 sec to run. I used force index on LastBump column with it and it will take around 6 sec to run still which is unreasonably long considering all columns are indexed and it only has 1m rows of data. I tried adding compsite index on all the columns in Trade_US which will be used to join and it doesnt help at all. I wiped the entire database and then recreated all the tables to see if it is the problem of high index fragmentation but still no luck. Totally out of ideas.. any help is appreciated.

Comment: I removed the mysql tag from the title of your question. See here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: @Strawberry trade offer relies on trade reply which foregin keys to the Trade_US. and it is used in the Max()

Comment: @Strawberry removing group by speeds thing up massively..like 2x. but still taking way too long

Comment: And how about playing around with max_heap_table_size and tmp_table_size? E.g: SET max_heap_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 64;
SET tmp_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 32;

Comment: @Strawberry its on a shared hosting server so i dont think i have the permission to do that

Comment: Well, no harm in trying! ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry took 11 sec (4sec faster).. guess its not a solution

Comment: You're summarizing over a megarow resulting from an eight-way join on a shared hosting server? You're using LIMIT to suppress the first 300 kilorows of a sorted result set? With respect, a half minute doesn't seem unreasonable for this workload. That's a lot of data slinging to get your ten rows.

Comment: @OllieJones tried on a PC and it took 2x the time to finish. Which i dont think it is the problem of the server. The problem is that it is using filesort i think

Comment: It has to create a temp table and then skip 300k rows of it. That's what file sort means.

Comment: @OllieJones well~~limit 10 takes more than 10s as well. So i wouldnt say its the problem of that

Comment: @Ollie Jones: "That's what file sort means" --- it's not http://www.percona.com/blog/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/